# materialize collapsible: how to determine which section is open?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I have a materialize collapsible which works as expected. Something similar to:

```
<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
   <div class="collapsible-header">Title1</div>
   <div class="collapsible-body" />
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="collapsible-header">Title2</div>
   <div class="collapsible-body" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

In a later process, when pressing a button I need a javascript function to modify its behavior depending on which section is open.

How can I determine which section is open?

I guess one possibility would be to store in a hidden element the index of the section when it is selected but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Materializecss add an `active` class to an open collapsible item by itself. So you can use it to understand which collapsible item is open.

You can use this jquery code :

```
$(document).on("click","ul.collapsible li", function(){

  var elem = document.querySelectorAll("ul.collapsible li");
  var index = "none"

  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].className == "active") {
        index = i;
    }
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = index;
  }

})
```

This code show index of opened collapsible item for you.

Here is complete example : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/c39ay5vt/)

Comment: Note that if you have added other classes in your <li> you'll have to use the .includes("active") method instead of just checking for equality.  ```if (elem[i].className.includes("active)) { ......```